# Import data from another dataframe for matching cells

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two data frames that I import from the excel sheets. There is some information I need to import from auxiliary dataframe to main dataframe if there is a matching.
My code:

```
auxdf =pd.DataFrame({'prod':['look','duck','chik']},index=['prod_team1','prod_team2','prod_team3'])

auxdf =     

            prod
prod_team1  look
prod_team2  duck
prod_team3  chik
 
# Main dataframe after importing from an excel sheet

maindf = 
            col1                     col2
mar_team1   aoo                      auxdf['prod_team1']   
mar_team2   auxdf.loc['prod_team2']  bla
mar_team3   foo                      auxdf['prod_team3']

# I want to import information from auxdf into maindf
for i in range(len(mdf)):
  for j in range(len(mdf.columns)):
    # Check if a cell value has a string called 'auxdf', if so, change its value
    try: 
      if 'auxdf' in maindf[maindf.columns[0]].iloc[0]: 
       maindf[maindf.columns[0]].iloc[0] = eval(maindf[maindf.columns[0]].iloc[0])
    except:
      pass
```

Expected output:

```
maindf = 
            col1      col2
mar_team1   aoo       look   
mar_team2   duck      bla
mar_team3   foo       chik
```

Need help to find most pythonic way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can create `Series` by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), get matched values by [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html), so possible mapping by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with `auxdf['prod']`, last reshape back by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s = maindf.stack()
s1 = s.str.extract(r"auxdf.*\['(.*?)'\]", expand=False)
print (s1)
mar_team1  col1           NaN
           col2    prod_team1
mar_team2  col1    prod_team2
           col2           NaN
mar_team3  col1           NaN
           col2    prod_team3
dtype: object

df = s1.map(auxdf['prod']).fillna(s).unstack()
print (df)
           col1  col2
mar_team1   aoo  look
mar_team2  duck   bla
mar_team3   foo  chik
```

Comment: Got inspired by my regex approach?

Comment: @mozway - No, solution was created earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would not have imagined this solution. What about the one in my question (use of two `for` loops, `try`,`eval`)? is it some lame approach?

Comment: @Mainland - In pandas is best avoid loops (if possible), so are prefered pandas methods. Also `eval` is not recommended - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex with [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) to match and replace the `auxdf` strings with the matching value:

```
out = maindf.apply(lambda s: s.str.replace(
        r'auxdf.*\[\'(\w+)\'\]',                 # extract key
        lambda m: auxdf['prod'].get(m.group(1)), # replace by matching value
        regex=True)
```

Output:

```
           col1  col2
mar_team1   aoo  look
mar_team2  duck   bla
mar_team3   foo  chik
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would not have imagined this solution. What about the one in my question (use of two `for` loops, `try`,`eval`)? is it some lame approach?

Comment: @Mainland for loops are slow in pandas so avoid them whenever possible. `eval` is even worse, this is a "high-power" function with a [lot of risks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) and should never be used unless you really know what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I hope it works for your solution,

```
import pandas as pd
import re
auxdf =pd.DataFrame({'prod':['look','duck','chik']},index=['prod_team1','prod_team2','prod_team3'])

maindf = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["aoo", "auxdf.loc['prod_team2']", "foo"],
        "col2": ["auxdf['prod_team1']", "bla", "auxdf['prod_team3']"]
    }, index=['mar_team1', 'mar_team2', 'mar_team3']
)
def replaceFunc(col):
    c = re.findall("auxdf\.?\w*\['(.*)'\]", col)
    if len(c) > 0:
        col = c[0]
        for i, v in zip(auxdf.values, auxdf.index):
            if v == col:
                col = i[0]
    return col
maindf['col1'] = maindf['col1'].apply(replaceFunc)
maindf['col2'] = maindf['col2'].apply(replaceFunc)
maindf
```